# PHP and RSS - Create 'score' based on description

Tags: php, parsing, rss

Hopefully this makes sense. I have a php script, magpierss, that parses a RSS feed and inserts the data into MySql and it works fine. I get the various parts of the RSS items into variables to make them easier to work with, so getting the pieces of the rss feed is not a problem.

However, my goal is to be able to have it filter the stories and only import certain ones. I want to automate this as much as possible, with some allowance for false positives/negatives because they will be manually verified after.

What I want to be able to do is set a list of keywords and 'weights' for each word. So when a new RSS item is parsed the script will create a 'score' based on the weights of the words in the description field.

For example:

```
stackoverflow = 10
very = 7
helpful = 8
```

So "stackoverflow very helpful" would get a score of 25

and also "stackoverflow is always very helpful" would still get a score of 25, because 'is' and 'always' are not keywords with weights assigned to them.

and "something random here" would get a score of 0, for having no keywords.

Then I could play with keyword weights and scores to figure out the best settings for filtering the rss feed.

Most of this I can figure out. I just need to know a way to parse the description of the item, and assign weights to specified keywords to create a 'score'.

Comment: Do this: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-bayes1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP comes with some functions that would help, such as strpos() and preg_match. The former would search for a specific string, and preg_match would search for regular expressions. You should create an array of the keywords and their weights, then run through each one and check to see if the description contains that value. If so, you increment a weight counter. Here's a simple example:

```
$keywords = array(
   'stackoverflow' => 10,
   'very' => 7,
   'helpful' => 8
);
$description = $feed->getDescription(); // or wherever
$total_weight = 0;
foreach ($keywords as $keyword => $weight) {
  if (strpos($keyword, $description))
      $total_weight += $weight;
}
return $total_weight; // total weight of this item
```

Something like that anyway. There are other ways to do it, but this should get you started.

Good luck.

Comment: This looks like what I wanted to do. Will be able to try it out shortly, will let you know how it goes.

Comment: I'd see that as good and simple example to do that. However, you could implement something with MySQL's Natural Fulltext Search described here (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-natural-language.html). In that case you can't assign the weights yourself, though. But the scoring itself works a little bit better than just checking if certain word exists.

Comment: I've used the full text search in the past. It's pretty useful for basic things like this. I tend to write my own, though, since my searches are more complicated than simply weighting based on keywords. But yeah, good call, Jasmo.

Comment: I have used MySql full text search in the past as well. But, I'm parsing a RSS feed, then putting it into the database. So I need to be able to get some sort of weight/score before it is put into the database, so a MySql search wouldn't help. I did use this code, with a couple minor corrections, and it works, so thank you. It is just missing a ) on line 9 and a } on line 11 to end the foreach statement.

Comment: Ah, good catch. Hard to double-check code when it's in this little text box instead of my editor. :) Glad it helped.